# Window width jquery with slice

Tags: javascript

Have this code:

```
 $(window).resize(function () {

     if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
         $(".projects").slice(0, 8).css("margin", "10px");
     } else if ($(window).width() > 480){
         $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
     };
 })
```

My question is:

- The slice 3,6 the default. How can make this display without window resize as default on page load.
- And how can do that if width greater than 480px then only do slice 3,6 all other slice is default option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a named function.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/ndyVv/)

```
function slice_it() {
    if ($(window).width() >= 320 && $(window).width() <= 480) {
        $(".projects").slice(0, 8).css("margin", "10px");
    } else if ($(window).width() > 480){
        $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
    };
}

$(window).resize(slice_it);
slice_it(); // <--- on load
```

And if I read your second bullet point correctly:

```
function slice_it() {
    if ($(window).width() > 480){
        $(".projects").slice(3, 6).css("margin", "10px");
    } else {
        $(".projects").slice(0, 8).css("margin", "10px");   
    }
}
```

#### *Edit:*

As per last fiddle in comment. If that is correct you should consider using `each` as in:

```
function slice_it() {
    if ($(window).width() > 480) {
        $(".projects").slice(0, 8).each(function(i) { // Pass index "i"
            if (i < 3 || i > 5) { // Here you check for index
                $(this).css("margin", "");
            } else {
                $(this).css("margin", "10px");
            } 
        });
    } else {
        $(".projects").slice(0, 8).css("margin", "10px");   
    }
}
```

In general, using `.css("margin", "");` in effect resets style to default.

You could also drop the slice all together and loop by each on `$(".projects").each(...`.

To break a jQuery `.each` loop return `false`. Example:

```
$(".projects").each(function(i) {
    if (i > 7)
         return false; // This aborts the each loop.
     ... do other stuff ...
});
```

Comment: Yes its ok but my problem when between 320 and 480px i do slice 0,8 margin 10 px and if the windows size greater than 480px then how to can reset that because its display?

Comment: @user3327101: I'm not sure I get what you mean. You want to undo the slice margin modification of `0, 1, 2, 7, 8`?

Comment: yes wanna undo from 0,8 slice when windows is greater than 480px?

Comment: @user3327101: Not sure I get it still, but does this look correct? http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/P9bNt/ – as in: you can reset to default by `.css("margin", "");`